# Function Convex Hull

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

Is there a code to finding the convex hull of a function? For example, lets take the function

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{1, r > 0.25}, {0, r > 0 && r < 0.25}}], {r, 0, 1}]
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
FunctionConvexHull[Piecewise[{{1, r > 0.25}, {0, r > 0 && r < 0.25}}], {r, 0, 1}]
```

So as to get the function `Piecewise[{{1, r > 0.25}, {4r, r > 0 && r < 0.25}}], {r, 0, 1}]`.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not familiar with the idea of "convex hull of a function". Could you expand on that?

Comment: The convex hull of two or more functions is the largest function that is concave from above and does not exceed the given functions. This is the definition given by Wolfram. Here's the link  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FunctionConvexHull.html

I might not have been so formal in the sense that I defined only one piecewise function. But the idea es to treat each of the segments of the function as a different function and find the convex hull of those segments.

Comment: there is some confusion here as your expected output does not seem to match the definition given. Or maybe I don't follow what "does not exceed the given functions" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
p = Plot[Piecewise[{{1, r > 0.25}, {0, r > 0 && r < 0.25}}], {r, 0, 
    1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[
 ConvexHullMesh[
  Flatten[Cases[Normal@p, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity], 1]~Join~{{1, 0}}],
  p]
```

[image]

```
p = Plot[Sin[r], {r, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[
 ConvexHullMesh[
  Flatten[Cases[Normal@p, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity], 1]~
   Join~{{0, -1}}], p]
```

[image]

Comment: This will work well, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The epigraph of the convex hull of a function `f` is the closed convex hull of the epigraph of `f`. This function tries to approximate the convex hull of the function `f` by a piecewise-linear `InterpolatingFunction` in the following way: First, we plot the function `f`. Next, we extract the points of these lines from the plot, join two corner points "at infinity" (it is perfectly sufficient to use any two points with x-coordinate at the interval boundaries and with y-component strictly larger than any other function value of `y`) and compute its `ConvexHullMesh`. From that, we merely have to extract the lower boundary points of the convex hull, sort them by their first component and interpolate.

```
ConvexHullFunction[f_, a_, b_] := 
 Module[{top, g, R, poly, pickers, plist, pts},
  g = Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}];
  pts = Join @@ Cases[g, _Line, All][[All, 1]];
  top = Max[pts[[All, 2]]];
  R = ConvexHullMesh[Join[{{a, top + 1}}, pts, {{b, top + 1}}]];
  poly = MeshCells[R, 2][[1, 1]];
  pickers = 
   Range[MeshCellCount[R, 0]] UnitStep[
     Subtract[top + 0.5, MeshCoordinates[R][[All, 2]]]];
  plist = DeleteCases[pickers[[poly]], 0];
  pts = SortBy[MeshCoordinates[R][[plist]], First];
  Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
]
```

Usage example:

```
f = r \[Function] Piecewise[{{1, r > 0.25}, {0, r > 0 && r < 0.25}}];
a = 0;
b = 1;
g = ConvexHullFunction[f, a, b];
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, a, b}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Another usage example:

```
f = x \[Function] -Sin[x];
a = 0;
b = 3 Pi;
g = ConvexHullFunction[f, a, b];
plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, a, b}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]